# Using COM object in C++ with MinGW compiler

Tags: c++, windows, com, mingw

I have an in-process COM server (i.e. DLL) I'd like to use from a C++ application that's to be compiled with the MinGW suite (using CodeLite IDE). I don't quite know where to start, any tips, suggestions or sample code anyone?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 6):

Just like a normal COM, you need to get its header files for the structure of COM Class and the CLSID, then

```
CoCreateInstance(CLSID, ..., ppv)
ppv->YourComAPI1(arg1);
```

Nothing different as developing under VC.

Comment: Thanks Francis. Also, I just came across this article at: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/com_in_c1.aspx which has help me get rolling.